# How do I set a variable to a regex string in Python Script for notepad++?

Tags: python, regex, notepad++, scintilla

I am trying to set a variable (x) to a string in a text file using regular expression.

Within the file I am searching there exists several lines of code and always one of those lines is a ticket number WS########. Looks like this

~File~

```
out.test
WS12345678
something here
pineapple joe
etc.
```

~Code~

```
def foundSomething(m):
    console.write('{0}\n'.format(m.group(0), str(m.span(0))))

editor1.research('([W][S]\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)', foundSomething)
```

Through my research i've managed to get the above code to work, it outputs WS12345678 to the console when the cooresponding text exists within a file.

How do I put WS12345678 to a variable so I can save that file with the corresponding number?

**EDIT**
To put it in pseudo code I am trying to

```
x = find "WS\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d" 
file.save(x)
```

**Solution** 
Thank you @Kasra AD for the solution. I was able to create a workaround.

```
import re  #import regular expression
test = editor1.getText()  #variable = all the text in an editor window
savefilename = re.search(r"WS\d{8}",test).group(0) #setting the savefile variable
console.write(savefilename) #checking the variable
```

To find a specific string within a file in notepad++ using the PythonScript plugin you can pull everything from 1 editor into a string and run a regex search on that.

Comment: why when in your file you have `WS12345678` the result is `WS99999999` and what your expected result ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am using regular expression so the name doesnt matter as long as it starts with "WS" and has 8 numbers following it.

Comment: so you want to extract it and what want to do with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result in your function then simply assign to a variable :

```
def foundSomething(m):
    return console.write('{0}\n'.format(m.group(0), str(m.span(0))))


my_var=foundSomething(input_arg)
```

and also for extract your desire string you can use the following regex :

```
>>> s="""out.test
... WS12345678
... something here
... pineapple joe"""
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'WS\d{8}',s).group(0)
'WS12345678'
```

Comment: How does this work if editor.research is a function. (I am using the PythonScript plugin for notepad++)

Comment: @Mason sorry i can't understand ? what you mean !

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to put the issue to words. 

editor1.research is also a function that is necessary since it is using a form of Scintilla to edit the text file and parse through it. 

`my_var = editor1.research('([W][S]\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)', foundSomething)` doesnt seem to work even when I include that return in the foundSomething function.


`x = find "WS\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d`
`file.save(x)`

Comment: @Mason your pattern is incorrect , checkout the edit

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Saves keystrokes. 

Apparently this is doable in notepad++ using a plugin called [Python Script](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/). My understanding is this plugin uses Scintilla + Python to enable the user to do anything. I need to be able to do this within notepad++ for this script to be useful.

Comment: @Mason sorry im not familiar with that !

Comment: THANK YOU! I Was able to make a workaround using what you wrote!!!

`import re
test = editor1.getText()
savefilename = re.search(r"WS\d{8}",test).group(0)
console.write(savefilename)`